# WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query

Tags: wordpress

My website not loading it can show connection timeout
[image]

and when I check error log it have this error ?
`WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM` wps9_options`made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpc4802e05bbcf59fd3b6350e8d3e5482c_socialⓥ1_7_0\Shutdown_Handler->__invoke, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpc4802e05bbcf59fd3b6350e8d3e5482c_socialⓥ1_7_0\Plugins_Handler->cache_plugins, set_transient, update_option`

Can you please help me to solve this issue.?